# Iterating thru list for lxml form submission

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I'm pretty new to Python and even more new to lxml, but what I'm trying to do seems really simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have this code with the goal of feeding a list of values (list object ISBN) to lxml to submit to a search field:

```
for i in ISBN:

    page.forms[0].fields['_nkw'] = ISBN[i]
    blah blah blah
```

I get this error after running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

page.forms[0].fields['_nkw'] = ISBN[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Obviously there has to be a way to iterate through a list of values to feed to a form, but clearly I don't know it :)

EDIT: FYI the code works fine when replacing ISBN[i] with hard input.
EDIT 2: contents of ISBN list object as requested:

```
['9781608319053', '9780321558237', '9781932735413', '9781416059516', '9781437708257', '9780781780582', '9781437701517', '9780323065801', '9780890420256', '9780323079334', '9781599417042', '9780781771535', '9781416031215', '9780312601430', '9780781775250', '9781591263333', '9780071748896', '9780133669510', '9781416045748', '9780781771566', '9781437728019', '9780323065849', '9781416066675', '9780735579965', '9780323078917', '9781437735826', '9781603595681', '9780321696724', '9780321558145', '9781933107981', '9780138024611']
```

Comment: What is the type of `ISBN`? Is it a list or a dictionary? What is its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is with your loop over and use of the ISBN variable. You don't need to be indexing it during your assignment, since `i` already holds an element of the list, extracted as part of the loop. You're getting an exception because you can't index a list with a string, even if that string came out of the list itself.

Instead, use `page.forms[0].fields['_nkw'] = i`.

Or if you need the index into the ISBN list for later code that you haven't shown, keep the assignment as it is, and change the loop declaration to:

```
for i in range(len(ISBN)):
```